# A command to put comments on the opposing page

Tags: memoir

In my earlier question, verso-recto was a bit of a red herring. Sorry. The revised question should be clearer.

In LATeX/memoir, I wish to set up a command to generate ‘extended marginal notes’ in which the notes would sit on the facing page of a double sided document. Ideally, I would be able to put the command near the text of interest and it would select the correct opposing page. Thus the note page would migrate with the text page during later editing. Such note pages would contain only the comments and would have different formatting than the rest of the manuscript. Moreover, the number of pages devoted to notes would be (much) smaller than the total number of pages.
Any advice would be appreciated

Any advice would be appreciated.

In response to questions:

1. Notes can appear on the left or right page as long as they are opposite.
2. If a text page doesn't call a note, the opposing page will be unaffected and will just continue the text.
3. Notes are limited to a single page.

Silly example. The note command would go near the highlighted text. The two pages would be formatted differently.
[image]

Comment: Do you have an example and a description of what should happen? What if there are no notes? What if there are too many notes? Does your document have (other) floats?

Comment: Are you wanting to have notes only on the left pages, and text only on the right?  Or text on the left and right, and the note appears opposite the corresponding text?

Comment: Some visuals of what you're after exactly would be of great help here. Perhaps mock something up in MS Word...

Comment: @cfr The document will contain images as well. It would be nice to handle them in the same fashion, but I could embed them in the text as well.

Comment: In terms of text flow, if an odd page has a note and the preceding opposite page is already full, what to you do?

Answer (score 2):

The paracol package can be used in two page mode, but there is no guarantee that the second page will be opposite the first.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Before\par
\lipsum[1]
\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}% 1 column on left page, * normal page numbers
First left\par
\lipsum[2]
\switchcolumn
First right\par
\lipsum[3]
\switchcolumn*
Second left\par
\lipsum[4]
\switchcolumn
Second right\par
\lipsum[5]
\end{paracol}
After\par
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image: two page demo]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will investigate it. With regard to your earlier comment, if an odd page calls for a note, a note page would be inserted prior to it and all the preceding pages would be 'pushed back'.

Comment: No, I can't just push things back because that would mess up the position of previous notes. I believe I must think in terms of two page spreads. I would have to fill any empty ages with some decorations or musings. That is ok in my application, but wouldn't be acceptable for others.

Comment: OTOH, it means that only even pages can have notes.  If you attempt to put a note on an odd page,  you could issue a \clearpage and purge any waiting floats.